# Cancel gesture in ViewGroup to let subsequent touch events re-flow

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

Lets assume I've a ViewGroup that handles a vertical scroll event. I already implemented the logic within `onInterceptTouchEvent` which will return true when the desired gesture is identified.

Lets say this gesture is a "Scroll down". When `onInterceptTouchEvent` returns true (scroll down is started) all subsequent touch events are going to be sent to my ViewGroup (correct :))

The problem is that as soon as the user scrolls **up** again (within the same gesture) i want to cancel myself as touch *handler* target and pass the events to my child view instead.

What should I use? calling `dispatchTouchEvent` within `myViewGroup.onTouch` as soon as i find the user started to "move up" ?

Answer (score 0):

One way to stop handling a gesture previously "intercepted" through `onInterceptTouchEvent->true` is to call `dispatchTouchEvent` within your `onTouch` method.

You'll need to forge your own MotionEvent (ACTION_CANCEL).